# Add dynamic formArray angular with validation

Tags: angular, typescript

Error on create form array

**core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.js:3528)
at setUpControl (forms.js:3405)
at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7382)
at FormControlDirective.wrapOnChangesHook_inPreviousChangesStorage (core.js:26975)
at callHook (core.js:4762)
at callHooks (core.js:4722)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4662)
at selectIndexInternal (core.js:9724)
at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:9685)
at BuildingPartsModalComponent_div_6_Template (test.component.html:37)**

Here is my code
**Html**

```
   <form [formGroup]="demoForm">
        <div formArrayName="demoArray" *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i=index">
          <input [id]="arrayItem.parts" type="checkbox" [formControl]="arrayItems[i]">
          <label [for]="arrayItem.volume" class="array-item-title">
            {{arrayItem.name}}</label>
          <div (click)="removeItem(i)">remove item</div>
        </div>
        <button (click)="submit()">Go</button>
      </form>
      <div (click)="addItem()">Add new</div>
```

**TS**

```
  demoForm: FormGroup;

  arrayItems: {
    parts: number;
    name: string;
    volume: string;
  }[];



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.arrayItems = [{
      parts: 11,
      name: 'Naslov',
      volume: '120'
    }];
    this.demoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      demoArray: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  get demoArray() {
    return this.demoForm.get('demoArray') as FormArray;
  }

  addItem() {
    const item = {
      parts: 11,
      name: 'Naslov2',
      volume: '120'
    };
    this.arrayItems.push(item);
    this.demoArray.push(this.formBuilder.control(false));
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    this.arrayItems.splice(index, 1);
    this.demoArray.removeAt(this.demoArray.length - 1);
  }
  submit() {
    console.log(this.demoForm.value);
  }
```

I made it much simpler that everybody can understand and to help me find the problem, thanks

Comment: Please read the docs, your .html don't work to control a FormArray. If you want you can also check this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541082/create-and-fill-reactive-formarray-angular-10/63551450#63551450 to know the diference when we using a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArray of FormGroup

Comment: @Eliseo what do you mean `.html` doesn't work? what makes you thinks so?

Comment: @RafiHenig, in your answer it's NOT [formArrayName]="i", it's [formGroupName]="i"

Comment: @Eliseo why `[formGroupName]="i"`?, the array of is of type `FormControl`  rather than `FormGroup` –

Comment: @RafiHenig, sorry,  [formControlName]="i"

Comment: @Eliseo you're right, fixed

Comment: @RafiHenig, you're going to want to kill me, apologies for me perfectionism, the "formArrayName" is not enclosed by `[` `]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addControl('control_name', new FormControl(''))` method to add a new control or form group dynamically to your form like below:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
});
```

**To add a FormGroup dynamically with validation use:**

```
this.form.addControl('address', new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    state: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
}));
```

**To add a FormArray dynamically with validation use:**

```
this.form.addControl('address', new FormArray([
     new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        state: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
]));
```

**Your HTML template for FormArray example**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="address">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let group of form.address.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="text" formControlName="city" placeholder="city" />
            <input type="text" formControlName="state" placeholder="state" />
            <input type="text" formControlName="country" placeholder="Country" />
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Visit here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields) to get more clarity to add/remove controls dynamically in Reactive Forms.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: @RafiHenig Your question is add dynamic FormArray with validation, so i answered that you can add any control dynamically using addControl method. you can add FormArray with Validation like this: `this.form.addControl('address', new FormArray([new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    state: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
})]));`

Answer (score 0):

Replace`[formControl]="arrayItems[i]"` with `[formControlName]="i"`, as demonstrated below:

```html
<form [formGroup]="demoForm">
  <div formArrayName="demoArray">
    <input *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i = index" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</form>
```